# Errors with splitting string

Tags: c#

I'm quite new to programming and I'm trying to split the string below to just 36.20C but I keep getting ArgumentOutOfRangeWasUnhandled. why?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string inStr = "Temperature:36.20C";

        int indexOfSpace = inStr.IndexOf(':');
        //stores the address of the space 
        int indexOfC = inStr.IndexOf("C");
        //stores the address of char C

        string Temp = inStr.Substring(indexOfSpace + 1, indexOfC);

        textBox1.Text = Temp;
    }
```

expected output : 36.20C

Comment: If "Temperature:" just an example, or the real value you want to remove from the string? If the latter then `var temp = inStr.Replace("Temperature:", "");

Comment: Do you want to remove the `C` from the end or why did you determine the index of it and use `Substring` with it?

Comment: @Nicholas Chan: Are you aware that you can select an answer for your questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [documentation for `Substring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you'll see that the second parameter is the length, not the end position. However, there is [an overload for `SubString` that only needs the start position](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and it'll return the string from there to the end of the string:

```
int indexOfSpace = inStr.IndexOf(':');
string Temp = inStr.Substring(indexOfSpace + 1);
```

Answer (score 4):

The second argument of [`String.Substring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) is the length but you have provided the end index. You need to subtract them:

```
string Temp = inStr.Substring(++indexOfSpace, indexOfC - indexOfSpace);
```

You could also remove the `C` from the end:

```
string Temp = inStr.Substring(++indexOfSpace).TrimEnd('C'); // using the overload that takes the rest
```

As an aside, you should use the overload of `IndexOf` with the start-index in this case:

```
int indexOfC = inStr.IndexOf('C', indexOfSpace);
```

Here is an easier approach:

```
Temp = inStr.Split(':').Last().TrimEnd('C');
```

Comment: Why is this answer being so heavily upvoted? It's a bad answer for the following reasons: 1. `++indexOfSpace` instead of `indexOfSpace + 1` is a dreadful piece of advice as it's modifying the variable unnecessarily; 2. the `indexOfC - indexOfSpace` parameter isn't required and 3. It's then full of superfluous advice on removing the "C" from the end of the string, which the OP doesn't require.

Comment: @DavidArno: 1) `indexOfSpace` can be modified since OP is only interested in the start-index of the token **after** the colon. Otherwise he always has to use `indexOfSpace + 1`. 2) `indexOfC - indexOfSpace` is required to show OP how to use `Substring` correctly since he assumes that the second aprameter is the end-index 3) I just wanted to show OP a different way to remove the `C` from the end instead of using `IndexOf` and `Substring`.

Comment: 1) Just because it can be modified, doesn't mean it should be. Only mutate the value of a variable when you have to. Your advice is bad practice. 2) There exists an overload that doesn't need the second parameter at all. 3) The OP didn't ask how to remove the `C`, so you aren't answering the question.

Comment: @DavidArno: it is not bad practise to assign the right value to a variable instead of always using the wrong+1. I have shown that there is an overload that takes the rest of the string, i just wanted to show first OP's approach and tell him what was wrong. I thought that he wanted to remove the `C` because he has determined the index of it and used it as second argument for `Substring`. But looking at the question again it could be that i was wrong. Then it's not clear why he's so interested in the index of the `C`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var arrayStr = inStr.split(':');
textbox1.text = arrayStr[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like

```
string Temp = inStr.Substring(indexOfSpace + 1, inStr.Length - indexOfSpace - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Second parameter of `Substring` is length. You must update as following:

```
string Temp = inStr.Substring(indexOfSpace + 1, indexOfC - indexOfSpace);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use string.Split().

```
string[] temp = inStr.Split(':');
textbox1.Text = temp[1];
// temp[1] returns "36.20C"
// temp[0] returns "Temperature"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string temperature = "temperature:32.25C";
Console.WriteLine(temp.Substring(temp.Trim().IndexOf(':')+1));
```

In substring, 2nd argument is length and if u do not specify any argument substring processes till the end of string.